# Handling a very large dataset in PHP regarding HTML tables

Tags: php, html, dom

So on a website let's say that a user can click on a button to load in a report. The problem is, some of these reports are easily 3000+ records coming back from a database. While the call is relatively quick (15 seconds for 20000 records), it takes a much longer time to add a table containing that data into the DOM.

Is there a way to speed this up at all, in php or javascript? I've already simplified the loop in php as much as possible.

Comment: don't show users 3k records at once, paginate

Comment: Either paginate, or summarise on the main page and provide a detail drilldown

Comment: Paginating makes too much sense honestly. Just need to figure an effective way of doing so.

Comment: the usual approach is .. LIMIT X,Y ...